# Proof by contradiction, Quantifiers

Tags: vector-spaces, quantifiers

Let $V$ be a vector space and $x, w$ in $V$. Prove there is a unique vector $v$ such that: $x+v = w$.

I planned on using a proof by contradiction, that is to prove For All v in V such that x+v =w, then get a contradiction, which would then prove There exists a $v$ in $V$, such that $x+v = w$. Is this logic correct, or am I misusing quantifiers?

Comment: Can we just get $v$ by subtraction: $v = w - x$?

Comment: i suppose so guess i was overthinking it, but i am interested in understanding if this would work, so that i could apply to other situations

Comment: if you are interested in learning proofs by contradiction, I recommend better examples, where contradiction truly serves the purpose:

1.  Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many primes: {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid's_theorem#Euclid.27s_proof}

2.  Proof that the real numbers are uncountable: {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_diagonal_argument}

3.  This one is not a proof, but uses a paradox to guard against bad constructs: {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barber_paradox}

Answer (score 0):

Well, why would you use contradiction here?

You have to show existence and uniqueness.

Let's start with **existence**. A good candidate vector for $v$ is of course $w - x$.

Since $w,x \in V$ and $V$ is a vector space, it holds that $w + (-x) = w - x  \in V$

Now, since $x + (w-x) = w$, we proved that there is a vector $v$ such that $x + v = w$ (take $v = w-x)$

Now, let's prove **uniqueness**.

Suppose $x + v_1 = w$ and $x+v_2 = w$, then $x + v_1 = x+ v_2$. Add $-x$ to both sides to obtain that $v_1 = v_2 \quad \square$

Why not use contradiction? Then, you must assume that such a vector does not exist (to show existence, not uniqueness). Then you must somehow get a contradiction. The only way to reach such a contradiction, from what I can see, is to show that the vector does exist, which defeats the purpose of proof by contradiction.